# SQL Error 10249 Hive with subqueries in SELECT clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to write query like

```
select (select count(1) from tableA), (select count(1) from tableB)
```

in Hive and there came an error
`10249 SubQuery expressions are only allowed as where and having clause`.

I think the grammar is right, is there any suggestion about this? Thank you!

Comment: The query seems to be incorrect. Moreover it doesnt have a closing ')' in the end. Now, what exactly you want to do? count of both tables ? can you use `select count(*) from foo union select count(*) from bar;`

Answer (score 0):

Some support of queries in the select was added in Hive >= 2.3, see this [Jira HIVE-16091](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16091) and docs: [Subqueries in SELECT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT)
If your Hive version does not support such subqueries in the select (and docs says such subqueries are not supported yet), move subqueries to the FROM and use CROSS JOIN or use UNION ALL + aggregation.

Using CROSS JOIN:

```
select a.cnt as count_a, b.cnt as count_b 
from
(select count(1) as cnt from tableA) a
cross join
(select count(1) as cnt from tableB) b
```

Using UNION ALL + aggregation

```
select count(case when src='A' then 1 else NULL end) count_a, 
       count(case when src='B' then 1 else NULL end) count_b
from
(
select 'A' as src from tableA
union all 
select 'B' as src from tableB
)s
```